# Why does Apple Music say that my student email is in use when trying to switch to a student account?

Tags: iphone, itunes, apple-music

I'm on the individual Subscription for Apple music right now. When I try switching to a student account (I'm eligible), it tells me that my student email is still in use. I might have used that email before, because a few months ago I got a new iPhone.

If I cancel my individual subscription and then try to sign into my student email, will I lose all my music?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have two Apple ID’s. Close the one with your student account and add/change the email on your personal account. Use “forgot password” with your student email to get into your student account if you don’t know the password.

BTW, [r/AppleMusic](https://www.reddit.com/r/AppleMusic/comments/4kctbj/what_happens_with_your_library_if_you_suspend/) says you have 90 days to pause a subscription without losing your data:

> Your library is kept on the server for 90 days - meaning, as long as
>   you restart your Apple Music 90 days of the previous subscription
>   coming to an end, you'll get all your library back.